Notation $y$ vs $y(x)$ for differential equation
Consider a linear differential equation, say, for the second derivative plus four times the derivative plus three times the "solution" function $x\mapsto y(x)$. Is there any good discussion around notation for:
$$y''(x)+4y'(x)+3y(x)=0$$
vs
$$y''+4y'+3y=0.$$
I have always used the first here, and like it because it stresses that the solution is a function (of $x$), but I feel like mathematically the second is more correct (a function $y$ vs its value at $x$, $y(x)$).
There is a balance to be struck between correctness and what helps student learning.
(Hoping this is on topic).

I'm not convinced that students learn subtle points from small differences in notation, at least not the subtle points we intend. I think that it is better to ask why you are writing extra stuff yourself. Could it be because you are distinguishing $y(x)$ and $y(t)$? Are the derivatives in $y', y''$ not with respect to $x$? (This would be unexpected and  worth flagging.) Alternatively, if everything is as usual, i.e. $y$ is a function of $x$ and derivatives are w.r.t $x$, why not just use the standard shorthand? Why make them jump through hoops?

If you are thinking of $y=f(x)$, then your differential equation could be either $y''+4y'+3y=0$ or $f''(x)+4f'(x)+3f(x)=0$.  Of course do this only after your students are familiar with using $y=f(x)$.

@GeraldEdgar surely we can also use $y=y(x)$. This is what I typically use, e.g. if we are talking displacement, I use $x(t)$, say $m x''(t)=a_0$ for constant acceleration. I am wondering about this vs $mx''=a_0$.

The issue suddenly disappears if one sticks to properly quantifying all variables. Your second equality is equivalent to the first one holding for all $x$ in the domain of $y$.

@JochenGlueck my issue is which notation is best for students. I am comfortable using either myself.

@Adam currently I am using the first and it isn't my intention to make students jump through hoops - this is just the way I started doing it.

For students, I disapprove of the notation $y = y(x)$.  (Of course it is sometimes seen in more advanced settings.)

@GeraldEdgar any particular reasons? I like it for engineering students, it conveying the variable(s) that $y$ depends on.

For beginners, it is important to distinguish between $f(x)$, a value of the function, and $f$, the function itself. More advanced students are expected to recognize (from the context?) which one of these it is, when $f(x)$ is written.  Writing $y=y(x)$ just makes it more confusing.

@GeraldEdgar does not $y=f(x)$ have precisely the same issue?

@JPMcCarthy No, because you use different names for different objects in y=f(x), while you use the same name for different objects in y=y(x). (At least if you take the modern definition of function seriously)

I would say the answer depends on the specific case and the specific context.
First and foremost, for autonomous differential equations, where there is no explicit appearance of the independent variable, I would more often than not prefer the second notation. Indeed, the equation you mention is autonomous, and I think that makes the mention of the explicit $x$ dependence more redundant.
After all, the solution to the equation is identical whether you call the independent variable $x$, $t$ or something else.
For non-autonomous differential equations like:
$$ y''(x) + kx = 0 $$
I think it is often very helpful to explicitly specify the independent variable like I did in the above.
Finally, a general note is that I believe students should become comfortable with a variety of notations. I think it actually helps them to separate in their own minds the essential concepts, that are true regardless of notation, from the more spurious ones.
Of course, when starting a subject it is much more important to be more strict with these matters. But also gradually, show students there is more than one way to express the same thing. It will help them a lot, especially when they try to gain more information from various sources, books, etc. which by nature, will all have their own different sets of preferred notational conventions.

I would make the 'often very helpful' even stronger. Without context $y''+kx=0$ is just not a well defined equation, it could be mean multiple different things and it is a priori not clear which one is meant.

@quarague Agreed. But "without context" is a very specific assumption. I am assuming that generally in many (if not most) cases, context is given. It is therefore more relevant to discuss the majority of cases -- where even there I still find the explicit notation more helpful. So I'm not in disagreement with you, just sharing the general thought process of mine in writing this.

Both are ok if you have constant coefficient linear homogeneous ODE's, as in your example, but there are some subtleties in other cases.
The difference between the two variants is that in the first case you're writing down an identity between numbers (left and right of the equal sign there are numbers), while in the second case you're writing down an identity between functions (i.e., maps from a subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$).
You made it quite clear that you want $y$ to be function $U \to \mathbb{R}$ in the modern sense of the word. I emphasize this because there's also the historical way to understand the word "function" and to write the ODE, which I'll mention at the end. But for everyone to be on the same page: in your setting $y(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ while $y\in \operatorname{Maps}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, and numbers and maps are different types of mathematical objects. There's no natural way to identify a number with a map, meaning there's no natural isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\operatorname{Maps}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.
A small problem with your first way of writing the equation is that you should have added a quantifier $\forall x \in U$. If you don't do this, that equation contains two free variables $y$ and $x$, and could/should be read as a condition on the pair $(x,y)$, where $x$ is a number and $y$ a map. One solution of that equation would, for instance, be the pair $x=-4/3$ and $y=(x\mapsto x)$ and many others, which is not what you want. But in practice, no one ever writes $\forall x$ next to the ODE, just like no one writes $\forall x$ next to the definition of a function $f$ when they declare $f(x)=x^2$. This habit has historical reasons that are related to the third option I'll mention at the end. I do suspect though that leaving out the $\forall x$ can confuse some students if you emphasize the modern notion of function a lot in your teaching.
Having said that, consider an ODE like in Amit's answer or the linear ODE 
$$y'(x)+3xy(x)=x^2\quad \forall x\in U$$ 
How to write it in your proposed second way? Just leaving out the $(x)$ would be problematic since the resulting equation $$y'+3xy=x^2$$should be an equation between maps but contains numbers $x$ and $x^2$ on both sides. The most common (and consistent) way to interpret numbers in an equation between maps is to see them as constant maps (given a $c\in \mathbb{R}$ interpret it as the map $f(x)=c$). But then the solution of that equation would be: $y=(u\mapsto \frac{x}{3} + C\exp(-3xu))$, which is again not what you want. Some people might object to what I'm doing here, saying "it's obvious that $x^2$ should not be interpreted as a constant function but as $x\mapsto x^2$". But suppose you see an ODE like $r'+3\sin(a)r=c^2$. It's natural to assume that $r$ is a function $r\in \operatorname{Maps}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. But how are we to interpret $a$ and $c$? As constants? Or should we maybe interpret $\sin(a)$ as the function $\sin$ and $c$ as a constant, or the other way round, $c^2$ as the map $c\mapsto c^2$ and $\sin a$ as constant? (We clearly cannot interpret both as functions). We would get different ODEs depending on the interpretation. Someone might object that if we don't use the letters $y$ and $x$ we just have to be more explicit. I dislike such ad hoc rules and believe that the person really wants to use the original notion of function.
In any case, if you want to take the modern notion of function seriously, the correct way to write the ODE $y'(x)+3xy(x)=x^2 \forall x \in U$ as an identity between maps is to either write
$$y'+3(x\mapsto x)y=(x\mapsto x^2)$$
or else to make up names for the functions $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto x^2$, say $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=x^2$, and then write $$y'+3gy=h.$$Both options look strange and would probably make calculations (separation of variables, variation of constants, etc.) very awkward. I've never seen someone do this.
So assuming you want to take the modern notion of function seriously (and not come up with ad hoc rules of what certain letters mean in which context), it seems like you're stuck with your first option of writing  $y'(x)+3xy(x)=x^2 \forall x \in U$.
From your comments below the question I see that you feel fine writing things like $y=y(x)$, and looking at your homepage, I see that you have a partial background in physics. This makes me believe that what you really want is to use the word "function" in its original sense. I've written about this in different places on Stackexchange, a starting point could be here
To make it short, if you don't interpret $y$ as a modern function but as a "function of $x$", hence as a number depending on the number $x$ (which might sound less strange if you read it as "a quantity depending on another quantity", so $y\in \mathbb{R}$ and not $y\in\operatorname{Maps}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$), then you can and should write
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+3xy=x^2$$
without any quantifier. The problem with the other equation also disappears if we write, say
$$\frac{dr}{da}+3\sin(a)r=c^2.$$

Although I'm not actually happy with some of these conventions in elementary mathematics...
(As I think I've said many times on this site...) One hazard here is that, often, "$y$" is the sacred name for the vertical coordinate in the plane. "$x$" being the horizontal. So, well, both can take any real values... the important point being that $y$ is not automatically "a function of $x$"... though, yes, graphing functions will have that be the case.
Although I've managed to understand an interesting bit of mathematics, I must confess that that sort of confusion did confuse me many years ago. The implicit idea that (in some context? unspecified?) $y$ was "of course" "a function of $x$". Ok, but, ... calling that function $y$? Ok, I guess if everyone in the room understands what's going on, it could be fine, but if this is the first thing someone hears it will be ... suboptimal, I think.
It's not so much even distinguishing the function from its pointwise values, but (as I seem to recall) distinguishing the vertical coordinate from a function which we may be graphing or visualizing.

Your confusion might stem from the common blurring between the modern notion of function and the original meaning of the word. When you say "a function of x" you're using the word in its original sense, and that's precisely the y on the vertical axis. It's a variable quantity that depends on x, like for instance a temperature that depends on time. On the other hand, the $f$ in $y=f(x)$ is what people since ~1940 call a function. That's not a variable quantity like temperature or number, does not depend on x and is not the thing on the vertical axis. Visually it's best thought of as the graph.

I like the latter expression as it is simpler/cleaner (not because it is more correct).  That is coming from the student perspective.
And I don't need you to push the "it's a function" thing at me, while I'm busy learning how to handle the characteristic equation.  There will be a lot of multi-step algebra going on.  And I sure don't feel like writing (x) on every term of every line of that explication.
This seems like another question where the instructor is more concerned about prissy correctness versus his students being concerned about it.  I'm not advocating being wrong.  But I think the emphasis should be on solving these equations, not on function concept.

For a contrasting instructor perspective, the emphasis should be on both solving the differential equation and understanding what is being done. Many student do initially struggle with the idea of solving for a function, as well as the notation "y(x)" and what this actually means. At least a few assignments where they are expected to grapple with this and be slow about it helps them digest the information, even if it is annoying in the moment. An instructor's job is not only to make problems easy in the moment, but to promote the learning that will make future problems easier to grasp.

That being said I do think it is in question whether this approach does improve student understanding substantially in a way that improves their future performance. For the majority of students, my belief is yes, but belief could be changed with data (not anecdote).

Thank you for your answer. I don't really understand the tone though. I am looking at my practise here and trying to find out which is better for student learning.

Marissa: (1) the OP says the format that is "more correct" is also the format that is cleaner.  So...you're actually doing some sort of reminder that this is a function...out of the blue, which also makes the notation more of a pain.

(2) The function concept is not critical to working with this diffyQ.  I have used second order constant coefficient diffyQs in EE, chemistry, physics, math, nuclear power, and weapons systems and have NEVER had an issue where the "it's a function" needed to be reminded or pushed.  It's just not a key thing to concern yourself here. Are you worried some sort of equation of a circle will emerge?  [And if so, just ask in the "solve for" statement, versus the writing of the diffyQ.

(3) this form of diffyQ has been solves since the late 1600s.  I.e. for over 400 years.  Most of which was done (and just fine) well before the current obsession with analysis and functions and the like.  [Heck...even if you need to obsess like that, there's no reason to push it here, with a strange notation.]

Without pedagogical experience be careful not to project your own experiences in differential equations on to other students. Instructors get to see all students' challenges with the concepts. The "it's a function" is to contrast with "it's a number" -- setting up an equation to solve for a function and not a single value is new for many students in DiffEq, especially those who are not EE's, those who are taking the course earlier in their college career, and those who still struggle with calculus I-II concepts. I still don't know which approach is more pedagogically valuable, to be clear.
